# Adding CSS loader to HTML button click

Tags: python, css, flask

I'm trying to add a "loader" while my flask application runs a task.

Here is my HTML for for my button

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
{# <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/leaf.css') }}"> #}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div id="loader"></div>
<div id="vo_budget_file_settings">
    {# <a href="/generatecleanbudgetfile" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Final CRO Budget File</a> #}
    <p>Please upload the final CRO budget File</p>
    <form class="" action="/generatecleanbudgetfile" method=POST enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <input type="file" name="data_file" accept=".xls, .xlsx, .xlsm"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Begin Format" onclick="loading();"/>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loading(){
      $("#loader").show();     
    }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the CSS that I've added:

```
#loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Any ideas on how to call this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it visible from the start, without ever showing it with javascript. Then hide it with js like so:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $("#loader").hide();
})
```

EDIT: I now realize you said on button click in the title. I am assuming you want to hide the loading screen on button click? If not correct me in a comment. Otherwise, use this code:

```
$("#button").click(() => {
    $("#loader").hide();
})
```

P.S.

Your script should be at the bottom of the body, and your CSS and JS (and my code) reference `#loader`, when the body has `<div id="loading">`

Comment: I actually only want the spinner to appear after the button 'Begin Format' is clicked

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if it matters. In this application, the CSS code is in a local folder `static/styles`

Comment: Ohhh ok. I didnt read the code very well apparently. In that case, what doesnt work right now? Currently doesn't it submit the form, bring up the loading wheel, and then go to a new page when ready? As far as I can tell the only issue is that you shouldnt be setting the url with js, you should `return redirect("../target_html")` in flask (or something similar, idk how your urls are set up)

Comment: The css location shouldnt matter. Just a tip though, you can use `href="./static/styles.css"` and bypass using `url_for()` Works for js, images, or anything else you put in static, not just `href=""`

Comment: I have edited the code with my attempt at your changes...what doesn't work is the wheel isn't appearing after I click the button

Comment: Any errors in the debug console?

Comment: no errors, it's executing the functions fine and returning my data. I'm not sure if my bootstrap is interfering with it?

Comment: Hmm. How do you hide it from the beginning?

Comment: Also, bootstrap has their own loading wheels, which might help.

Comment: I figured out what the issue is. It was browser cache. I had to clear it using "Shift" + reload for the updated css files to reflect. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Weird. I’ve never had that issue with flask. I usually just restart the server if I update html, and everything else is fine. I’m glad it works now!